# SpagoBI 5.0 - blank screen while entering datamart deployed from SpagoBIStudio 4.1

Tags: tomcat, spagobi

I've got some difficulties with SpagoBI. I am using this system for the first time on my local PC, so I tried to prepare a project basing on tutorial: https://youtu.be/0wdOwN7OUDo

In order to prepare my project I used:

- SQL Server 2014,
- driver: sqljdbc42,
- SpagoBI 5.0 (on Apache Tomcat/7.0.47),
- SpagoBIStudio 4.1,
- Java: jdk1.6.0_45 for SpagoBIStudio, jdk1.8.0_161 for SpagoBI.

And I accomplished the following steps:

- configuring both environments (paths for Java)
- creating new data source connection in SpagoBI
- creating .sbimodel, server connection, database connection
- creating datamart (right click in SpagoBIStudio on Business Model > create > datamart
- uploading datamart and model on server

After that  in SpagoBI > Documents development, I can see my datamart and another samples. Unfortunately after entering my project it loads a while, and then i can see blank area instead of browser with objects I created in BIStudio before. The samples load...

Did anyone have such problem?
Thank you in advance for your help!

J

**EDIT**
In SpagoBI log i found this:

org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException:  Table [Fact_Orders] contains logical column name [`customer_type_id`] referenced by multiple physical column names: [`customer_type_ID`], [`customer_type_id`].

But I'm wondering now, where seems to be the problem? This is true that in my Fact table I've got foreign keys named the same as primary keys in dimension tables.
Does it mean that I have to change e.g foreign key names in Fact table? Or maybe that could be enough, if I change that in SpagoBIStudio model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, changing columns name in Fact table in database helped. Strange restriction...